# Custom button next to exporting overlaps on the To: of the range picker

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to add a customButton on exporting on highcharts which say 'o yeah'. The real code does more, and uses a custom icon, but for this example i'm using circle. The code is:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
    customButton: {
        x: -25,
      y: 1,
      symbol: 'circle',
      onclick: function(){ alert('yeah') }
    }
  }
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vdfhnyp/1/)

THe problem is fairly obvious. It overlaps the To: selector from the range selector. I could do hackery and push the range selector further, but then when there's title, it wouldn't work. I'm looking for a more proper solution, which'd work in all widths, devices and wouldn't conflict with other settings (like title).

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/6vdfhnyp/3/ .Add similar icons to debug the issue

Comment: I would categorise this as the 'hackery' i talk about. Basically trying to fit the icon in however much space is available. I'd never hear the end of it from product. If you hover on the export icon, the icons are overlapping.

Doesn't solve the problem where i want the icon to become the PART of the top line.

Answer (score 1):

It was pretty simple. I just had to move the rangeSelector to the left a little.

```
rangeSelector: {
    x: -10
},
```

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hassan_rehman/6vdfhnyp/8/)

Comment: true hackery every where

Comment: but this isn't hackery. I wanted another thing on the right .. so i shifted the rightmost thing to the left ...  not hackery  .. unfortunately, still can't do it on the project because of the feature not available in the old version ..  but stackoverflow question is still answered

Comment: As you mention in question post _I could do hackery and push the range selector further, but then when there's title, it wouldn't work._ is same what added as answer. Have a good day :-)